# System.ObjectDisposedException without calling Dispose() in async code in asp.net core 2 controller code

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm having a weird problem in an ASP.NET core 2 controller. Even though I'm not calling anytime `Dispose()`, I'm having exception at

```
_db.AesConnexions.Add(CurrentAesConnexion);
await _db.SaveChangesAsync(); //exception here
```

> **System.ObjectDisposedException**: 'Cannot access a disposed object. A
>   common cause of this error is disposing a context that was resolved
>   from dependency injection and then later trying to use the same
>   context instance elsewhere in your application. This may occur if you
>   are calling Dispose() on the context, or wrapping the context in a
>   using statement. If you are using dependency injection, you should let
>   the dependency injection container take care of disposing context
>   instances.'

This code is inside a

```
protected async Task SetupNewAesConnexionAsync()
{
    _db.AesConnexions.Add(CurrentAesConnexion);
    await _db.SaveChangesAsync(); //exception here if s/Task/void/
}
```

which I call in the constructor or in

```
public IActionResult Index()
```

Upstairs, I got the following constructor (ctor)

```
public CookieController(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor,
                        MyDbContext dbContext)
{
    _accessor = httpContextAccessor;
    _db = dbContext;
}
```

(maybe an important detail, `CookieController` is actually used as subclass by `ContactController` ):

```
public class ContactController : CookieController
{
    public ContactController(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor, MyDbContext dbContext)
        : base(httpContextAccessor,  dbContext)
    {
        InitAes();
    }

    private async void InitAes()
    {
        await FindOrCreateAesConnexion(); // exception here when
        // I have protected async Task SetupNewAesConnexionAsync()
    }
}
```

(I checked that `CookieController` ctor was called before `ContactController` ctor: it is)

I register types in startup.cs:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MssqlLocalhost")));

        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
    }
```

Basically I'm retrieving data in DB from cookie ID information, eventually updating the DB (adding information). I thought that maybe I'm messing with mixed sync and async code (calling async code from constructor), but I can't see any problem or link with the exception described.

Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It would be great if you could provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It is unclear where `SetupNewAesConnexionAsync` is called and how `DbContext` is registered.

Comment: I'm looking forward for this. In the meanwhile, SetupNewAesConnexionAsync() is a protected method of the controller.

Comment: The DbContext is registered with the usual DI packed with the Microsoft.Extensions:  services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer( Configuration.GetConnectionString("MssqlLocalhost"))); which works fine in other controllers (they use others DbSet).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is the `CurrentAesConnexion` coming from? Is it local to the scope of the controller method?
One obvious issue I see is that the `SetupNewAesConnexionAsync` method returns `void` rather than a `Task`. That way, the actual "await" will have effect and will result the execution to complete before moving on:

```
protected async Task SetupNewAesConnexionAsync() {}
```

**Update**
Updating the answer to encompass the full resolution.

Turns out the issue is how the connection to the database was initialized. It's currently being done in an `async` method, called from the constructor but never awaited.
The fix is to follow `async-init` pattern (I've invented the term, nothing official), described [here](http://mkartak.blogspot.com/2017/06/how-to-initialize-instances.html). Here is the updated code:

public class ContactController : CookieController
{
    private readonly Task initTask;

```
public ContactController(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor, MyDbContext dbContext)
    : base(httpContextAccessor,  dbContext)
{
    this.initTask = InitAes();
}

private async Task InitAes()
{
    await FindOrCreateAesConnexion(); // exception here when
    // I have protected async Task SetupNewAesConnexionAsync()
}
```

}

Now, wherever the connection is used, the `initTask` should be awaited first, as follows:

```
protected async Task SetupNewAesConnexionAsync()
{
    await this.initTask;

    _db.AesConnexions.Add(CurrentAesConnexion);
    await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Comment: The CurrentAesConnexion is actually one of the DbSet of the DBContext, which comes from DI (which works fine with the other controllers).

Comment: I actually changed the void for task to have coherent async parts and added a private async void InitAes() { await FindOrCreateAesConnexion(); } called from the ctor. This just doesn't help a bit: same exception.

Comment: Can you share a sample project?

Comment: `async void` methods are good candidates for threading related issues...

Comment: Also, how are the types registered in the DI container? What's the scope for those?

Comment: I know we should have 100% sync or 100% async code, but sometimes it might be done cleanly non ? How do you call -or I should say await- an async method from the constructor or any sync method ?

Comment: There are mechanisms to achieve it. I've blogged about that some time ago. Have a look at: http://mkartak.blogspot.com/2017/06/how-to-initialize-instances.html

Comment: I edited and added the types registration. Working on providing a more complete sample.

Comment: the exception is "following"  where is the first/last wait call in sync code. Looks like there is something there.

Comment: That just means that an exception has been thrown on the Task executing that code. When you try to access the result of the task (either by referring to the `Result` property or using `await`), that's when you get the exception. But it actually had happened earlier on a separate thread.

Comment: Artak, can you edit your answer or post a new one with your initialization trick this.initializationTask = this.InitializeAsync(); ? It solved my bug. I'll do some checks but, you should receive the "accepted" tag after confirmation !

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your issues is that when you're calling the async `InitAes()` method it is not being called with the await keyword. Because this call is not being awaited, execution of the method continues before the call is completed. Therefore the injected dependencies have been disposed of.

```
public class ContactController : CookieController 
{

    public ContactController(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor, MyDbContext dbContext) : base(httpContextAccessor,  dbContext)
    {
         await InitAes();
    }

    private async void InitAes()
    {
        await FindOrCreateAesConnexion(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, we cannot have await inside non async method.